# AzerothCore MSB6006 "cmd.exe" exited with code 1

Tags: azerothcore

I've been trying to build the Azerothcore, and everytime I do it comes up with the same area in the title and blockquote.

> MSB6006 "cmd.exe" exited with code 1

I've done everything exactly as the thing told, including to make sure Visual Studio was set to "Release" and not "Debug" before building.

Comment: are you running it from a terminal? so you can see what the actual error is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what it looks like, you have ran the build successfully and decided hit the play button on visual studio. Make sure you have worlserver as your startup project. Also make sure your visual studio has the correct directory to where the worldserver is executed from since you'll need several dependencies.
You can run the files manually by looking for them in your bin, where they are compiled. Your path should look something like:
**c:\folder_where_azerothcore_project_is\bin\Release**

Here you should have files like worldserver.conf and authserver.conf configured properly with your database data. You should also have some dlls:

- libmysql.dll
- libcrypto-1_1-x64
- libssl-1_1-x64

You can find them in your OpenSSL bin folder and Mysql library folder.

After all of these configurations, try to run the executable files and you're good to go!